# How to Convert Numeric date to textual display in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

I need to display the Date in words. For example  `27-JUL-1991` should display like  `Twenty seven of JULY, Nineteen Hundred ninety one`

How can I achieve this in oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (column_name,'HHsp:MIspth AM ddspth/mmspth/yyyyspth') 
FROM table
```

It gives you everything.. you can modify as you want...